# What means this error?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-boot

What means this error ?

```
17:20:04.091 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - 
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/rest-api] threw exception 
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.ResultProcessingException: Failed to execute request: 
{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (c:Category) optional match (c)-[:subcategory*..1]->(s) OPTIONAL MATCH (i:Item)-[r:type]->(c) 
RETURN id(c) as neo4jId, c.uuid as uuid, s.uuid as uuidParent, c.name as name, s.name as nameParent, 
COUNT(r) as numberItems ORDER BY c.name","parameters":{},"resultDataContents":["graph"],"includeStats":false}]}] with root cause
   org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found
```

Comment: Can you provide HTTP status code of your call. It appears to be 404 which would mean servlet endpoint doesn't exist for specifiied URL/Parameters

Answer (score -2):

i guess, you have problem with the protocolo communication , client-server, try  to check what respond the  server